# Converting C# class to JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, class

Take a look at this basic class:

```
namespace AcmeWeb
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public class Person 
    {
        public Person(string firstName, string lastName) 
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(firstName);
            }

            this.FirstName = firstName;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the best translation of this into JavaScript?

This is what I'm thinking:

```
(function(namespace) {

    namespace.Person = function(firstName, lastName) {

        // Constructor

        (function() {
            if (!firstName) {
                throw "'firstName' argument cannot be null or empty";
            }
        })();

        // Private memberts

        var _ = {
            firstName: firstName
        };

        // Public members

        this.firstName = function(value) {
            if (typeof(value) === "undefined") {
                return _.firstName;
            }
            else {
                _.firstName = value;
                return this;
            }
        };

    };

})(AcmeWeb);
```

Comment: First of all, why are converting it to JS? If its because you need that object on the Client you can parse your class into JSON and pass it to the client, then you will be able to treat the JSON object on the client exactly like your class on the server.

Comment: I'm just exploring making JavaScript more OO.

Comment: There is something called Script# that is a compiler for C# to JavaScript: http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp I've never tried this, but the idea sounds great to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use real getters/setters in javascript. See John Resig's [post](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) for more information. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/xhB7E/).

```
(function(NS) {
    NS.Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
        if (!firstName) {
            throw "'firstName' argument cannot be null or empty";
        }

        var FirstName = firstName;
        this.__defineGetter__("FirstName", function(){
            console.log('FirstName getter says ' + FirstName);
            return FirstName;
        });

        this.__defineSetter__("FirstName", function(val){
            console.log('FirstName setter says ' + val);
            FirstName = val;
        });
    }
})(AcmeWeb);

var p = new AcmeWeb.Person('John', 'Smith');
p.FirstName;          // => FirstName getter says John
p.FirstName = 'Joe';  // => FirstName setter says Joe
```

Comment: @Kirk Woll - http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/xhB7E/. I only tested this out in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

```
var AcmeWeb = {
    Person: function(firstName, lastName) {
        if (!firstName) {
            throw "'firstName' argument cannot be null or empty";
        }
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }
};
```

Then you can new up a `Person`:

```
var person = new AcmeWeb.Person("john", "smith");
```

Comment: I like this answer because what good is a accessor/mutator really doing here in the JS code other than making so you have to call `person.firstname()`

Answer (score 2):

It should be like

```
(function(namespace) {
    namespace.Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
        var firstName    = firstName || 'default',
            lastName     = lastName || 'default',
            moarPrivates = 'foo';

        return {
            firstname: function(value) {
                if( value ) {
                    firstName = value;
                    return this;
                }
                else {
                    return firstName;
                }
            },
            lastname: function(value) {
                if( value ) {
                    lastName = value;
                    return this;
                }
                else {
                    return lastName;
                }
            }
        };
    };
}(AcmeWeb));

var Andy = AcmeWeb.Person('Andy', 'Foo');

Andy.firstname('Andreas').lastname('Baaaaar');
console.log('Hello, my name is ', Andy.firstname(), ' ', Andy.lastname());
```

By returning on object literal, all local variables from the constructor function are closured. That is why they are private and only accessible from within the Person object. The public methods are those which you enclose into the returning object literal.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/GkFu4/1/